# Cocos 2d body & its fixtures

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, fixtures

Well I try to implement the run action to move a specific sprite towards the specific destination, I can achieve that using the below code snippet.

```
[spriteA runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2 position:realDest],[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],nil]];
```

But now the problem arise that the sprites moves perfectly but the fixture & bodydef of that sprite stays on it previous positions. Please guide me that how can I move the body & fixture along with the sprite using 'runAction' or in any other way.

Thanks & Regards,
Zahur

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply force/impulse to the body and then set the sprite position to body position.